# Legendre transformation of Geometric Random Variable

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

I am wondering what the Legendre transform of a Geometric r.v with success parameter $p$ is. I have that the logarithmic moment generating function is $\Lambda(t)=(t+\log p)-\log(1-(1-p)e^t)$ but cannot get the algebra to fall nicely when trying to compute $$I^*(x):= \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}(tx - \Lambda(t)) $$ Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Could you please show me what you did? As it stands it's hard to give a good answer as I don't know the difficulty you had (this is standard site policy, to ask for these things).

Comment: A trivial freebie: $0<p\le1$ for a geometric distribution. In the edge case $p=1$: $$\Lambda^\ast(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=1\\+\infty&x\neq1\end{cases}$$

Comment: If $0<p<1$ then: $$\Lambda^\ast(x)=\begin{cases}(x-1)(\ln(x-1)-\ln(1-p))-x\ln x-\ln p&x>1\\-\ln p&x=1\\+\infty&x<1\end{cases}$$